# Make the comment input wrap

Tags: feature-request, comments, android-app

When entering text in a comment in landscape (to have the larger software keyboard) - it appears as a single line of text. This makes writing/editing comments harder than it needs to be.

Can the comment text input be changed to wrap text in the same way as the question body input (i.e. the same as a html textarea)?

[image: Writing/editing a comment is all on one line]

It's not relevant in portrait:

[image: Comment write/edit in portrait]

This is with:

- App version 1.0.42
- Samsung Galaxy S2
  GT-I9100
- Android 4.1.2

Comment: Why... why is it not wrapping in horizontal view. I'll take a look at this, thanks.